# Unable to start Spark's "start-all.sh" on EC2 (rhel7)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, rhel7

I am trying to run standalone Spark-2.1.1 by triggering `/sbin/start-all.sh` in an EC2 instance (RHEL 7). Whenever it runs, it asked for the root@localhost's password and even tough  I've given the correct password, it throws me - `root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.` error.

Irrespective of this error when I hit `jps` in the console I could see the Master is running.

```
root@localhost# jps 
27863 Master
28093 Jps
```

Further I checked the logs and found this-

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/06/12 15:36:15 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 27863@localhost.org.xxxxxxxxx.com
17/06/12 15:36:15 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
17/06/12 15:36:15 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
17/06/12 15:36:15 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
17/06/12 15:36:15 WARN Utils: Your hostname, localhost.org.xxxxxxxxx.com resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using localhost ip instead (on interface eth0)
17/06/12 15:36:15 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/06/12 15:36:16 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://localhost.org.xxxxxxxxx.com:7077
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.1.1
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://localhost:8080
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
17/06/12 15:36:16 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

I am trying to figure out why I am unable to start my worker nodes. Could someone help me out with this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hostname if it is correctly resolved. 
If you're using `localhost`, make sure it is resolved in your `/etc/hosts` file.

let me know if this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I am actually using the system ip address instead of 'localhost' (just renamed for security reasons). And yes, the hostname is correctly resolved and the issue still persists.

Comment: still, try resolving `localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file and see if it works, like this:

`192.168.y.xxx hostname`
`192.168.y.xxx localhost`.

If it does then you will have to make changes in your spark conf (spark-env.sh) for the property `SPARK_LOCAL_IP`.